# Store image as logic file (in db by using binary format) or physical file (in the server)

Tags: web-development, code-quality, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what are the best tips for storing images in a database?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105191/what-are-the-best-tips-for-storing-images-in-a-database)

In those study cases of image storage,

- An image that change only once in a while, if it changes at all (like an image for an article)
- The image case from above is not only one image but over 10, that link to the same article
- An image that have changes very often (like a banner image for a website)
- The image above is huge

What is the best approach for each case? What is the "right/faster" way to do this task in each scenario ?

Comment: lots of dupes http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=images+in+database+or+filesystem

Comment: Also Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/files-in-the-database-or-not

Comment: @maple_shaft Excellent link, thank you. Answered my question =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to provide a link only answer, but this microsoft research paper goes into great detail on the advantages of file system vs database for file storage:

[To BLOB or Not To BLOB](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64525/tr-2006-45.pdf)

Comment: How much has storage changed over the last 7 years?

Answer (score 1):

My default answer to the default image storage question is to do both -- store the original in the database, but use caching to serve it out of the filesystem. It gives you all the advantages of the database -- that is transactional updates, easier backup management and transportability as you can just deploy from the database while also preserving the filesystem's advantages of speed of serving static content.

Comment: Hmm nice idea, the problem is the cost in server and database. In small projects, I think, this is the best idea. +1